# null returned by NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableString which I append other strings to.

When I print the String I get null.

in the .h file

```
NSMutableString *name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *name;
```

in the .m file

```
@synthesize name;

-(IBAction) a {
if (uppercase == 1) {
    [name appendString:@"A"];
    NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
}
else
    [name appendString:@"a"];
    NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
}
```

I get the following print out when triggering the action.

> name: (null)

Why is this returning null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you never initialized it.  Something like:

```
- (id)init {
    // Standard init code here...
    self.name = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
}
```

... to ensure that you have a valid object to work with?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something similar but without stringWithString. ;)

Comment: Ah yes, setting it with something like self.name = @""; will set it to a regular NSString*, which will compile, but will not work like you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the value of 'name' anywhere in your code? In the code you've pasted in your question, 'name' never gets set. You can't append a string to something that doesn't exist - you're effectively trying to append a value to null, which is why nothing gets returned.

So I guess my answer would be: based on the code you've shown, name never has anything assigned to it. If you are assigning a string to 'name', your problem is elsewhere, but you'd need to post the code for the assignment etc.

Comment: Is there a difference in assigning an NSString and an NSMutableString?